# unable to retrieve mutated data from getter

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vuex

I'm trying to render a d3 graph using stored data in vuex. but I'm not getting data in renderGraph() function.

**how to get data in renderGraph()?**

Following is store methods.

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import * as d3 from "d3";

Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    subscribers: []
  },
  getters: {
    getterSubscribers: state => {
      return state.subscribers;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    mutationSubscribersData: (state, payload) => {
      state.subscribers = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    actionSubscribersData: async ({ commit }) => {
      let subsData = await d3.json("./data/subscribers.json"); // some json fetching
      commit("mutationSubscribersData", subsData);
    }
  }
});
```

Below is parent component

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MyGraph /> // child component rendering
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import MyGraph from "./MyGraph.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MyGraph
  },
};
</script>
```

Below is child component.

**MyGraph.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <svg width="500" height="400" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getterSubscribers"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["actionSubscribersData"]),
    renderGraph(data) {
      console.log(data); // DATA NOT COMING HERE

      // MyGraph TO BE RENDERED WITH THIS DATA 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.actionSubscribersData();
    this.renderGraph(this.getterSubscribers);
  }
};
</script>
```

I have tried mounted, created lifecycle hooks. but did not find data coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is race condition. `actionSubscribersData` is `async` and returns a promise. It should be waited for until data becomes available:

```
  async mounted() {
    await this.actionSubscribersData();
    this.renderGraph(this.getterSubscribers);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be delay for the `actionSubscribersData` action to set value to store. Better you make the action `async` or watch the `getter`. Watching the `getter` value can be done as follows

```
watch:{
  getterSubscribers:{ // watch the data to set
    deep:true,
    handler:function(value){
      if(value){ // once the data is set trigger the function
        this.renderGraph(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```